# angular 2 meteor InjectUser

Tags: javascript, meteor, angular

I work with angular 2 meteor.
I can not to get user in constructor:

```
export class Page extends MeteorComponent {
currentUser:Meteor.User;
constructor() {
    super();

    console.log(this.currentUser);
    //undefined
}

click(){
    console.log(Meteor.user());
    //Object{...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need ?

```
import { InjectUser } from 'angular2-meteor-accounts-ui';
...
@InjectUser('currentUser')
export class Page extends MeteorComponent{
  currentUser: Meteor.User;
}
```

Edit: A bit more explanation
In the above code, you have just declared currentUser type not actually assign it to anything yet, so the undefined result is obvious.